# Laravel-9: Problem in auth view which isnt working as it was fine in laravel-8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

i moved to laravel-9 but when i tried to make auth than auth has done but its view is like raw html, i have tried a lot solutuins from google but nothing works, in laravel-8 i was using these commands to make auth:

```
  composer require laravel/ui

  php artisan ui vue --auth

  npm install && npm run dev

  php artisan serve
```

can anyone please suggest any solution. Thanks

Comment: You are using vite or mix webpack?

Comment: there is by default file vite.config.js and when i run these commands then a file named mix.webpack generates

Comment: Please check your resources/view/layouts/app.blade.php, is there a @vite resources or standard webpack <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>?

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> this script is there

Comment: OK. Then if you are using vite and when your are run npm run build vite starting in your command console you should remove it and add @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']).  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite

Comment: now it showed error Vite manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\public\/build/manifest.json

Comment: what if i wants to remove the vite and work with webpack because that is comfortable

Comment: You can run npm run build now but if you want to migrate to the webpack, this is official guide: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix

Comment: after removing the result is still same